# Multiple keyboard hooks in .NET and Delphi

Tags: .net, delphi, keyboard-hook

I have an application with both .NET and Delphi components
I register to a keyboard hook (with SetWindowsHookEx) in both components.
I first register in .NET, and later in Delphi.

The problem is, **the hook delegate in Delphi is called before the hook delegate in .NET.**

According to MSDN, the hook chain is just a list, and as I understand the delegates should be called according to the order of registration.

Anyone has an idea what is going on here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please cite the part of MSDN that confused you? Give a link and a brief quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misunderstood. The [hook overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959.aspx) in MSDN describes it like this (emphasis added):

> The [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) function always **installs a hook procedure at the beginning** of a hook chain. When an event occurs that is monitored by a particular type of hook, the system **calls the procedure at the beginning** of the hook chain associated with the hook. Each hook procedure in the chain determines whether to pass the event to the next procedure. A hook procedure passes an event to the next procedure by calling the [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644974.aspx) function.

Therefore, it's precisely the expected behavior if your Delphi hook is installed last and is called first. There's nothing "going on" at all.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that, need to sleep more.

Answer (score 1):

The hook list is not a list, but a chain. Newly installed hook keeps the reference to the previous one. This means that the hook, installed later, is always executed before the hook installed earlier.